# Hacking with Linux

Tags: kali-linux, backtrack

Are Kali Linux or BackTrack distros to go if I want to learn hacking, or is it better to install only the tools I want to another distro?
I've already used Kali in the past but I didn't like it very much.
I've read somewhere that the tools are hard to install, so is it better to have one of the distros? And if so, which one?

Comment: Thats distrib-independant. I am sure you won't learn.

Comment: @PeterHorvath What do you mean by that? Why wouldn't I learn?

Comment: I checked your posts and now I think, maybe you want. It will be visible only on longterm. It is not really important, which distro do you use, especially in the era of the virtualization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use some wellknown distribution, for example debian. But really not the distrib which is important.

The main problem is that hacking is an interdisciplinary thing. You can't really good learn directly hacking, it weren't really efficient. If you want to do things efficiently, you need to learn things which don't have to do with hacking directly.

As a first thing, set up your own server and try to make that secure.

Next to that, look for well known security holes on the net. (How? Where? It is another important saga.)

The default install of your distribution probably fixed them. Look, what was really the bug, and how was it fixed. Then try to re-open that on your system, and test if it works. Then close again. http://security.stackexchange.com were a good site for this if you want to get support.

It will be much better if you could do such problematic things on a sandbox, which could be a virtualized server on your host. *Deep* system administration knowledge, especially around virtualization, will be an important thing for anyway.

Until then, you will have to learn linux/unix deeply (*very* deeply! You will smile to see this actual post about finding distros...), and C deeply as well. http://serverfault.com and http://superuser.com can be good support sites for you.

If you want to do things hard, it will take at least years, if you have a hacker/programmer/linuxer brain. If you not, you don't have any chance.

If you do things until a half year relatively hardly, I think, you will learn enough to know, in which direction you need to go further. From that point, things will depend only on your curiosity.

On the longterm I must mention: probably you won't earn too high wages with that. If you fill this some more... worthly IT knowledge (programming frameworks on current languages), you will get out finally much better.

If you can, it is very good if you start at least a IT-related BSc course on a regional education institute (university). First, you will be able to learn things which can't be learned from the internet. Second, you will be able to get wellpaid jobs with that, where you will find also very good ways to learn, on the defensive side.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even know where to begin, the most I can do in linux is to setup ArchLinux, I'm beginning with python, but anyway, thank you

Comment: @m477h3w Python is OK to learn programming, but isn't to learn hacking. But it can be a good first step before C & asm & shellscripting.

Comment: you should add: "you probably need a good lawyer if you plan to hack other people's machines"

Comment: @pqnet Nor I and he ever stated if he ever should try to do anything against the law. I even suggested him to do some other in the IT, or at least orderly work on the defensive side.

Comment: @pqnet I don't want to hack anyone. I just want to know how it all works

Comment: @m477h3w I described a yearlong plan for you, maybe it were too big price for a simple answer? Finally, you could end up even as a group leader of a security analyst work group by an ethical hacking company. So you could have good wage as well, but there are very few such positions, and a such job needed at least 10 years for you, I think.

Comment: @PeterHorvath I'm glad you spent time to write this, it shows me the path better than anything I've found before

Comment: @m477h3w hacking is pretty similar to breaking in a school at night to copy the test sheet the day before: first you collect information, like looking for open windows or learn where the janitor keeps his key, then you get in exploiting whatever mean possible, you do what you came for then finally you leave trying not to leave traces. You need a lot of common sense and knowledge to even think about it, and experience of the defending party point of view. And to succeed you need to be smarter and/or more motivated than the ones which are trying to keep you out.

Comment: @pqnet I gave advice to a young layman what to do if he wanted to go in this direction. He probably never programmed on any language. He is very far (at least years) to be once a hacker, and if he will be one, it won't be my fault (if it were even a fault), but his success. And there is no guarantee if he tried to use this knowledge for any criminality, and juristic formula of the IT criminality is very problematic at this time (for example you can be an IT criminal if you "breaks" some patent manipulations of some big IT companies).

Comment: @m477h3w If you are doing total normal things on the net, there is no cause to not use your normal name. If you are doing problematic things, you had to use simple name which can be everywhere found (for example, "red hat" or "john"), thus you can't be identified by them. Such chaotic nicknames can only be used if your _goal_ to be identified what you did on this name (i.e. I am googling for your nick and I will se everything what you did on this name. For example, I can see your probable real name and photo. If your nick were "joe", I couldn't do that).

Comment: I wouldn't use this name if it were for bad things, it just looks cool ;)

Comment: @peterh Reacting to my old posts - I doubt you would know my real name or photo, since I used that nick only on SO, I found many different people using that shitty nick elsewhere. Since I have deviated from this idea of "hacking" and concentrated more on actual developing. I know many more languages now, but I still didn't learn C as I didn't feel the need so far.